# Fetching data from mysql database using a crontab

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to use a crontab to fetch data from a remote database and then save the data on local machine.

The data is fetched using a following php script

```
exec("mysql --user='username' --host='host' --password='password' --database='db' --execute='select * from table'", $output, $return);
file_put_contents("/Path_to_file/file.txt", $output[0]);
```

And this is the crontab

```
06 13 * * * /usr/bin/php /Path_to_php_script/file.php
```

Now the php script works fine if I run it normally from the browser or from the terminal but when i run it as a crontab it manages to save the file to the specified location but the file is always empty.

Also, the crontab user is the same as the user when the file is executed through the browser or terminal.

So does anyone have any clue why the same script does not work when executed through the crontab?

Comment: Do you have wget on your Linux server? Use that in the cronjob to browse the correct url

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now it works with curl. But still, it would be nice to know why the code above doesn't work.